# Parsing HTML code in R

Tags: xml, r, rcurl

I am currently trying to parse HTML code in R. Currently I am using the XML and RCurl package to parse the information.

```
webpage <- getURL("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0809504/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers")
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
x <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table", xmlValue)  
# do some clean up with regular expressions
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\n"))
x <- gsub("\t","",x)
x <- sub("^[[:space:]]*(.*?)[[:space:]]*$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
x <- x[!(x %in% c("", "|"))]
head(x)
```

However, what I really want to do is parse only a particular part of html starting with

`<h4 class="dataHeaderWithBorder">Writing Credits`

and ending with

`<h4 name="cast" id="cast" class="dataHeaderWithBorder">`

Any help would be appreciated immensely.

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://www.imdb.com/conditions): _"Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below._ The `omdbapi` R package may have what you need vs violate the ToS.

Comment: Oh yeah, oops, sorry about that. I can just use the .list files available from IMDB.

Comment: If you run into a similar problem with another site that allows for this, rvest might be a better package for what you are trying to do. See Hadley's [tutorial](https://github.com/hadley/rvest)

Comment: Indeed, I am currently using rvest for another problem, however I have encountered a problem with the scrapping. When I scrape the information it produces a vector with 3 rows. I need to convert this vector with 3 rows into 1 single row. I have been looking at functions such as paste, but no joy yet.

Answer (score 1):

The question did not specify precisely what output is desired but here is a self contained example that returns the indicated node.

```
library(XML)

Lines <- '<a>
  <b class = "Z">abc - ABC</b>
  <b class = "Z">xyz - XYZ</b>
  <b>def - DEF</b>
</a>'

doc <- htmlTreeParse(Lines, asText = TRUE)
xpath <- "//b[@class = 'Z' and contains(., 'xyz')]"
getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), xpath)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
<b class="Z">xyz - XYZ</b>
```